# How to use unfixed json structure in a column with EntityFramework 7?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

Consider this example:

```
    public class Config
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public DateTime? DateCreated { get; set; }
        public int? ValueInt { get; set; }
        public decimal? ValueDecimal { get; set; }
        public string ValueText { get; set; }
        public DateTime? ValueDate { get; set; }
        public virtual ConfigValueJson ValueJson { get; set; }
    }



    public class ConfigValueJson
    {
        public ClanoviKartice ClanoviKartice { get; set; }

        public ClanoviKartice2 ClanoviKartice2 { get; set; }
    }


    public class ClanoviKartice
    {
        public DateTime? DatumZadnjegPrintanja { get; set; }
    }
    public class ClanoviKartice2
    {
        public DateTime? DatumZadnjegPrintanja { get; set; }
    }



    public class ConfigEC : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Config>
    {
        public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Config> builder)
        {
            builder.HasKey(e => e.Name);
            builder.OwnsOne(c => c.ValueJson, optons =>
            {
                optons.ToJson();
                optons.OwnsOne(c => c.ClanoviKartice);
                optons.OwnsOne(c => c.ClanoviKartice2);
            });
        }
    }
```

This forces json to be of this structure:
`{ "ClanoviKartice":{"DatumZadnjegPrintanja":"2019-12-09T00:00:00.000Z"}, "ClanoviKartice2":null }`

I want to be able not to specify all types in json, like this (EF throws exception):
`{ "ClanoviKartice":{"DatumZadnjegPrintanja":"2019-12-09T00:00:00.000Z"} }`

This limitation forces me to have the same structure for all rows where there is a value, or create a separate column for each structure. They should've just treated no json property as null value.

The ideal would be to have multiple properties with different types in Config for the same JSON column.

Comment: What is the difference between ClanoviKartice and ClanoviKartice2? Since it looks like same data structure.

Comment: It's just a POC. Point is that I need more than one type.

Comment: Since you are dealing with ef those types will have to be defined in order to work, regardless the fact it is a json column. As for avoiding null there is no option to set json serialization options at this moment. That will probably be added in the future. Have a look here https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-ef7-release-candidate-2/#limitations